# How to force low ssh-encryption

Tags: ssh, backup, encryption, arm

I regulary backup my computer to my BananaPi with a Hard Disk connected. The Problem is, that the transfer speed over ssh is pretty low because the Pi can't handle AES 256 encryption quick enough. Since this is a save LAN, I'd like to lower the encryption strength to get higher datarates. Preferably only sometimes, because when I administrate things, I would feel better with a higher encryption.

Comment: It is unclear that lowering encryptin will accelerate backup. bottleneck more likely located with disk I/O. However, you can try to reactivate remsh (remote shell, aka rsh, port 23) of old, for testing purpose.

Comment: it's definitely not disk I/O since pv /dev/zero > x.bin gives me arount 39 MB/s while over ssh I only get 15

Comment: You should rather consider setting up some FTP server. If you are running over trusted LAN, I don't think encryption is needed.

Comment: You could use `rsync` in its *daemon* mode where it can use a direct tcp connection with optional compression.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck trying different values of the `Ciphers` option in your [ssh_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config). Additionally try reducing or disabling compression if your network connection is fast enough to cope to take some extra load off the CPU.